# Is this possible in Mockito: when(SomeClass.getIntance()).thenReturn(myMock)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I'm working with some legacy code, where I have to implement a new Handler. And in this handler, there's an object which is unfortunately initialized by the framework using some hard-coded property file, like this:

```
// new code
public class NewHandler extends RootHandler {
  Util util = Util.getInstance(); // !!!Problem: throws NPE in unit-testing env

  // defined in the legacy framework, can't change its signature
  @Override
  public void doSth() {

  }
}

// legacy code
public class Util {
    static public synchronized Util getInstance() { 
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new Util();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    private Util() {
    MyObj obj = LegacyCode.load("myConfig.cfg"); // !!!Problem: throws NPE in unit-testing env
    ...
```

}
}

Now the problem:
in `Util()`, it's always loading the config file from a fixed location, therefore it always throws NPE when I run my unit tests, since there's no "myConfig.cfg" on the unit-test classpath.


One workaround is to extract the business logic into a separate method, passing in an Util object, so that I can pass in mock objects during tests:

```
// new code
public class NewHandler extends RootHandler {
  Util util = null;

  // defined in the legacy framework, can't change its signature
  @Override
  public void handle() {
    Util util = util.getInstance();
    doHandle(util);
  }

  public void doHandle(Util util) {
    ...
  }
}

// legacy code
public class Util {
  ...
}
```

**My question** is: 
is there any other way to workaround this problem, without adding the doHandle() method? I tried the following code using Mockito:

```
Util myUtil = mock(Util.class);
when(Util.getInstance()).thenReturn(myUtil);
```

but it didn't work, Util.getInstance() didn't get replaced with myUtil.

any thoughts? 

**UPDATE**: Things are getting a little bit messy, as I found out that Util.getInstance() is called everywhere in the legacy code base. So even if I have a mocked Util in my new code (as was described by Stas below), things will still break when Util.getInstance() is called elsewhere.
 Obviously I couldn't add new Constructors to every single class in the legacy code that calls Util.getInstance().

This is the reason I'm asking "whether it's possible to have something in Mockito like  **when(Sth.getInstance()).thenReturn(myMock)"** 
if yes, the all the calls to Util.getInstance() can be mocked and won't cause problem anymore.

Hmm....Any idea?


***********************************************************************

**SOLUTION**:  I think the solution in my case is [PowerMock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427750/using-powermock-or-how-much-do-you-let-your-tests-affect-your-design)

Answer (score 1):

You should try smt like

```
 public class NewHandler extends RootHandler {
     Util util;
     //Pass instance
     NewHandler(Util util) {this.util = util;}
 }
```

Than you will able to use it `new NewHandler(Util.getInstance())` or `new NewHandler(mock(Util.class))` in your tests.

PS for further info you can read about [Service locator](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/ServiceLocator.html) and [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Comment: For added bonus, add a default constructor which calls `this(Util.getInstance());` so your normal code work like before.

Comment: @ZeissS, I would not do this in new code. I think classes should be used in same manner in "normal code" and tests. But as workaround with legacy code it's can be good solution.

Comment: @Stas Kurilin: I meant it solely for backward-compability. Sure, new-code should either use a factory or some other meanchism do resolve those dependencies.

Comment: @ZeissS, in this case, I totally agree with you.

Comment: I guess the new Constructor only works if there's a default Constructor in the legacy RootHandler (which is fortunately the case in the legacy code, it has both a default Constructor and some other). Otherwise it'd be impossible to add another parameterized Constructor in the new code.

Comment: @Tumer, You can create new constructor that takes arguments for `RootHandler` 's super and Util as optional parameter, can't you?

Comment: @Stas, things are getting a little bit messy, as I found out that Util.getInstance() is called everywhere in the legacy code base. So even if I have a mocked Util in my new code by adding a new Constructor, things will still break when Util.getInstance() is called elsewhere.
Obviously I couldn't add new Constructors to every single class in the legacy code that calls Util.getInstance().

Comment: @Tumer, With bad code you can't write good tests. It can be good task to generate such constructors with some additional util which will change your source code.